# How to fix the command-not-found databases?

Tags: command-line

My recently installed Ubuntu system is currently having issues with the command-not-found hook:

```
josh@sirius:~$ invalid-command
Unable to open binary database /usr/share/command-not-found/programs.d/i386-main.db: File read error
Unable to open binary database /usr/share/command-not-found/programs.d/i386-multiverse.db: File read error
Unable to open binary database /usr/share/command-not-found/programs.d/i386-restricted.db: File read error
Unable to open binary database /usr/share/command-not-found/programs.d/i386-universe.db: File read error
invalid-command: command not found
```

I have tried reinstalling and `dpkg-reconfigure`ing both `command-not-found{,-data}` but these don't seem to have fixed it. Is it safe to delete these files, or do I have to run some program to recreate them? I should add that this was originally a 32-bit install that I reinstalled with 64-bit without formatting the disk.

Answer (score 15):

On `20.04.4` LTS, this helped me:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall command-not-found
```

The `-data` package is no longer there.

I was getting something like:

```
$ kbounce
Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug
Please include the following information with the report:

command-not-found version: 0.3
Python version: 3.8.5 final 0
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
Exception information:

unable to open database file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/util.py", line 23, in crash_guard
    callback()
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 90, in main
    cnf = CommandNotFound.CommandNotFound(options.data_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.db = SqliteDatabase(dbpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.con = sqlite3.connect(filename)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Right now, I get:

```
$ kbounce

Command 'kbounce' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install kbounce
```

**Edit 2020-12-16**

The problem returned after a reboot. I debugged `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py` and found the following:

```
$ ls /var/lib/command-not-found/ -l
total 3076
-rw-r----- 1 root root 3141632 gru 16 08:17 commands.db
-rw-r----- 1 root root    3253 gru 16 08:17 commands.db.metadata
```

So, the DB is there, but the permissions are wrong.

So I executed:

```
$ sudo chmod -R o+r /var/lib/command-not-found/
```

Now, it works again.

Comment: With me, the problem was that `import apt_get` wasn't working in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py`, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57147858/14681457) did the trick!, so symlink `apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so`.

Comment: +1 for the chmod.  That was all I had to do to fix it.

Comment: You are answering a different question.

Answer (score 1):

The database files for the 64 bit version are named `amd64-*.db`, while the 32 bit version ones are named `i386-*.db`. So apparently you have the 32 bit package installed when you should've had the 64 bit package.

What does this output?

```
apt-cache policy command-not-found{,-data}
```

Comment: In here, because apparently I can't format comments nicely: http://pastebin.com/6fqTMDAn

Comment: @dutchie, hm. Does this list both `amd64-*.db` and `i386-*.db` files? `ls /usr/share/command-not-found/programs.d/`. If so, it might be the old package just failed to remove those for some reason. So just manually removing them should fix your problem.