# Could not find command-not-found database

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, updates

## problem

Any command does not return a list of options, e.g. for the non-existent `plp`:

```
$ plp
Could not find command-not-found database. Run 'sudo apt update' to populate it.
plp: command not found
```

Running `sudo apt update` runs normally, and the problem persists.
**Edit:** the problem is that there is no list of suggstions with which package could provide that command, or which command is close to it, *not* that the command is wrong. I expected an output like:

```
Command 'plp' not found, did you mean:

  command 'pgp' from deb pgpgpg (0.13-9.1build1)
  command 'pp' from deb libpar-packer-perl (1.049-1)
  command 'pcp' from deb pcp (5.0.3-1)
  command 'clp' from deb coinor-clp (1.17.5+repack1-1)
  command 'php' from deb php7.4-cli (7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4)
  command 'tlp' from deb tlp (1.3.1-2)
  command 'plm' from deb plm (2.6+repack-3)
  command 'pyp' from deb pyp (2.12-2)
  command 'lp' from deb cups-client (2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1)
  command 'lp' from deb lprng (3.8.B-2.2)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

## investigation

[ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323765/how-to-fix-the-command-not-found-databases)
tells me to run `apt-cache policy command-not-found{,-data}` returns:

```
command-not-found:
  Installed: 20.04.4
  Candidate: 20.04.4
  Version table:
 *** 20.04.4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     20.04.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
N: Unable to locate package command-not-found-data
```

but `command-not-found-data` is not an installed command. Furthermore, on the [Debian bug tracker for command-not-found](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=932712), the command `sudo update-command-not-found` is also not recognized.

I think the database should be located at `/var/lib/command-not-found`, which is empty.

thanks for any help, It's been nagging me for quite some time!

Comment: I know that it is not a valid command, but normally, this should return a list of suggestions, and the packages that can provide that command.

Comment: That's because there is no such command.  Are you sure that the commands that you are trying to use are valid commands?  What exactly are you trying to do?  Please make sure that you provide the entire command that you are trying to enter alongside the output of each command.

Comment: It won't return a list of suggestions if it has no clue what you are trying to do.  So what is it that you are trying to do?  This seems like it could be an XY problem

Comment: I edited the question with clarification (output from WSL ubuntu in stead of native)

Answer (score 3):

So in the end, it was because `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py` has `import apt_pkg` which was not properly installed on my machine. So [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57147858/14681457) solved it, by:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```